# Cannot access Vue CLI dev server from other devices in network

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I have a Vue CLI project started using npm dev server (npm run serve)

I have this:

```
 App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.1.2:8080/
```

At local computer I can access the site with browser using both: local and network addresses.

From other devices of local network - cannot (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

Problem is not in port/firewall: I have tried different ports (e.g. flask server works good (and other devices can access) with one of the ports I tried).

Please help.